# In Iinux kernel, what is the meaning of .data and .long?

Tags: kernel

```
.data
  ENTRY(sys_call_table)
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_ni_call)           /* 0 */
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_exit)
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_fork)
    ...
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_vfork)             /* 190 */
```

I read this source code. I can't find `.data` or `.long` definition in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [assembler directives](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo-Ops)—special directions to the assembler which tell it to do something different, rather than inserting a processor instruction into the compiled machine code.

The [`.data` directive](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Data.html#Data) tells the assembler to emit the following instructions onto the end of one of the subsections of the `data` section of the executable.  Normally, machine code is emitted into the so-called `text` section of executables, whereas non-executable data such as global variables are stored in one of the so-called `data` sections.  The different sections have different memory permissions at runtime, among other features.

The `.long` directive is equivalent to the [`.int` directive](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Int.html#Int), which just says to insert a literal numeric value into the machine code.  So `.long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_ni_call)` inserts the numeric value of the location of the `sys_ni_call` symbol.

So putting these together, a `.data` directive followed by a `.long` directive results in the assembler putting specific integer values into one of the `data` sections of the resulting object code.  These values will be non-executable, and they may be read-only or read-write, depending on how the permissions of the `sys_call_table` subsection of the `data` section are configured.